# PHP session_decode not working?

Tags: php

I have a session_set_save_handler function write.

```
function write($id, $data) {
    GLOBAL $mysqli_link;

    $data = session_decode($data);
    $data = $data['user'];

    $access = time();
    $stmt = $mysqli_link->prepare("REPLACE INTO sessions VALUES (?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $id, $access, $data);
    $stmt->execute();

    return true;
}
```

and this:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION["user"]   = "josh";
```

my problem is, I want to get this user (josh) but session_decode is not working. what is wrong?

if I use session_decode it write NULL into my db. if not, it write `user|s:4:"josh";`
I want just josh.

Comment: What does the `$data` looks like?

Comment: this is $data: user|s:4:"josh"; it is from $_SESSION['user']

Comment: Try to `var_dump($data)` right after you decode it.

Comment: NULL, if i decode it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Manual:

> **bool** session_decode ( string $data )
>
> `session_decode()` decodes the serialized session data provided in
>   `$data`, and **populates the `$_SESSION` superglobal with the result**.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-decode.php

Note the `bool` return value and the bolded line about `$_SESSION`. This is not doing what you think it's doing. Have you tried simply `$_SESSION['user']` instead?

Probably also useful to note (from the same page):

> Please note the **unserialization method is not the same as `unserialize()`**. The serialization method is internal to PHP and can be set using `session.serialize_handler`.

Comment: $_SESSION['user']; returns josh but I think its not the right way to get this, since I'm using session_set_save_handler to handle with session, I think I need to get this "user" from data value sent to function write. or is it ok to get user from session[user] inside this function?

Comment: Why would it be a problem to access the `$_SESSION` superglobal directly? PHP is not going to encode the `$_SESSION` superglobal, destroy and unset it, then hand the data off as an orphan to the function, so you can no longer access `$_SESSION`. You could implement a [customer `SessionHandler`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php) ([more here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html)) as an option, however, and use either the `write` or `close` handlers.